# clang-tidy ignores readability-identifier-naming on Windows

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I want to use clang-tidy to enforce the style guidelines of my company. I'm working on Windows 10. I've installed LLVM v6.0.1.
Here's my test file:

```
class foo_bar
{
public:
  foo_bar() = default;

private:
  int bar_;
};
```

And here's the command line I'm running:

```
clang-tidy.exe -checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming' -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase} ]}" test.cpp -- -std=c++11
```

clang-tidy doesn't output any error (I was expecting an issue with the class name). I fail to see where my mistake is. Can anyone guide me?

I tried the same command line with the same file on Ubuntu 16.04.4 and I have the desired result:

```
1 warning generated.
C:\Users\Cyril\dev\clang_test\main.cpp:1:7: warning: invalid case style for class 'foo_bar' [readability-identifier-naming]
class foo_bar
      ^
```

Comment: it looks like you have to use CamelCase with your class names (FooBar)

Comment: Well I was hoping clang-tidy would check that option, and seeing that the name is badly formatted, output an error. Am I misunderstanding what clang-tidy is supposed to do?

Comment: If you want this to be an error instead of a warning use -warnings-as-errors

Comment: I tried it, still no output. I tested the same command line on Linux, it's working fine. Is it possible that clang-tidy has an issue on Windows?

Comment: Test it a little more - it seems that it actually runs default checks instead of running the one you want. Since there is nothing wrong with your code in terms of default clang-tidy checks there is no output. See my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that clang-tidy on Windows has a problem with a combination of `-checks` and `-config` options.

You can actually put everything into `-config`:

```
clang-tidy.exe -config="{Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming', CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.ClassCase, value: CamelCase} ]}" test.cpp -- -std=c++11
```

This produces the desired output

```
X:\test.cpp:1:7: warning: invalid case style for class 'foo_bar' [readability-identifier-naming]
class foo_bar
      ^~~~~~~
      FooBar
```

Tested on LLVM 6.0 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Windows Cmd Shell (cmd.exe) then the problem is with the use of single quote (') in the `-checks` option in this line

```
clang-tidy.exe -checks='-*,readability-identifier-naming' ....
```

if you change this to (using (") instead)

```
clang-tidy.exe -checks="-*,readability-identifier-naming" ....
```

then it will work correctly.

This is not an issue when using bash on windows only when running in cmd.exe